# Perl CGI onclick call perl subroutine

Tags: perl, cgi

I want to call a perl subroutine in Perl CGI. I know I need the onClick event but not sure how to use it correctly to call "TestSbub". Can anyone help?

```
<input type="button" value="submit" onClick="process('')">


sub TestSub {
    ###Do some code###
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't, at least not directly.

`onclick` is a client-side JavaScript function. CGI code runs on the server.

To call a Perl sub you need to:

1. make an HTTP request to a URL
2. have your server trigger a CGI program for that URL
3. have that program call the sub (e.g. by examining values in the query string to decide to call it).

The simple way to make that HTTP request would be to use a link or to submit a form. If you want to use JavaScript then you can assign a value to `location` or use the `XMLHttpRequest` object.

Comment: OK thanks how about getting it to just call a separate script

Comment: Pretty much the same thing. You just need to use a different URL.